# resizable table like stackoverflow textbox editor

Tags: jquery, html, resizable

I would like to know if it's possible to make a table resizable just like stackoverflow text box editor in ["Ask Question" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Have you tried googling "jquery resizable"? Gives you pretty much what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflow uses the [TextArea Resizer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer) for jQuery. Demonstration [here](http://www.itsavesyou.com/TextArea_Resizer_example.htm).